# how to divide a cell into few variables by its pattern?

Tags: sql-server, split, cell, alphanumeric

I have a few columns like these:

- D1D2D9D10D11
- MaintainedMaintainedRaisedMaintainedMaintained
- PATPATNPLNPLPAT
- 11011

I need to separate them apart to make it look like:

```
D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
Maintained  Maintained  Raised  Maintained  Maintained
PAT PAT NPL NPL PAT
1   1   0   1   1
```

Is there anyway I can do it?

Thanks in advance!
Tilly

Comment: So what is the problem you have? You must have well defined rules for each column where to add spaces?

Comment: We got the data from xml and this is what we've got.

Comment: You really need something else to be able to process the data automatically, because D1D2D9D10D11 could become D1D 2D 9D 10 D11 or D1 D2 D9 D10 D11 -- and just trying guess this based on numbers and letters is going to be totally impossible.